# audio sound localization using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to localize a sound by using an array of microphones, the localization is done based on the sum and delay algorithm. I'm trying to to do the same in machine learning. I don't have much knowledge about machine learning but I think it can be done using linear regression using stochastic gradient ascend, I'm using a sine wave as input, I have to optimize the delay to and find out at which delay I get the max gain at the output. can anyone provide an example for linear regression using stochastic gradient ascend

Comment: The machine can search for identical sounds on the different audio tracks and pass them to the localization equation. The search for identical sound is "machine recognition of audio signals / waveforms. it's going to be identifying things. you may find that the shazam variety of algorythm is the most efficient for recognizing audio.. it transforms signal into FFT make a fingerprint of the FFT graph peaks.... I would search for machine comparison of similar signals from different tracks... The localization is very easy, it's just an equation of the time differences.

Comment: So, perhaps research sound ID and send results to the time comparison equation.  a lot has been written and many libraries and research are available for automatic sound recognition, you will have divide the microphone signals into soundclip snippets and compare across all different tracks for same one.

Comment: I'm a new·bie in this field don't know that much machine learning. So what are you suggesting me to do?

Comment: It's a very cool topic and very relevant to current technologies, so it's worth studying. I would have searched for "comparing sound machine learning" and "audio recognition machine learning", search for pages related to a variety of any search words that you can think of in the search phase. first result is this: https://medium.com/@awjuliani/recognizing-sounds-a-deep-learning-case-study-1bc37444d44d

Comment: intro science page: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/audio-voice-processing-deep-learning/ .... https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+learning+sound+comparison&oq=machine+learning+sound+comparison&aqs=chrome..69i57.5702j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: using microphones, you would have the same sound at different amplitudes and times, so it's logical to substract the sounds found with peak detection / amplitude threshold for loud sounds. NN would also work for it.

Comment: what I'm thinking of that finding the gain . for a particular delay value that to be calculated using machine learning we will get max gain and that delay value can be used to predict the angle. I'm not quite sure about it that it doable  or not

Comment: I don't know about the gain technically in this context. gain is the volume amplification on a synthesizer from my limited experience, so it refers to amplitude... the key notions of the topic are... locating identical sounds on different audio recordings, using peak detect, substraction, machine learning... triangulation of distance based on identical sound capture time from different locations. triangulation is a very key notion of the topic. commercially i believe gunshot microphone localizing has been used in NYC to track gun shots in realtime, over the echo/noise.

Comment: I don't see why machine learning should be necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: machine learning is used to find the source that produces sound at different frequencies and optimize the delay value to find the max gain